# Bootstrap 3 nav-pills not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav-pills

I have followed the documentation but I am unsure why my `pills` are not working.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="assets/css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <nav class="nav navbar-nav">
         <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li>blah</li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your expected result ? Can you try to insert some `<li>` tags to see whether it works properly ?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

FYI: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills

Please also attach the assets/css/style.css file specified above. It is suggested to place the Bootstrap CDN at the top of `<head>`, above your custom css file.

=========== Updates ===========

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="nav navbar-nav">
         <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Blah</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Is that your expected pill effect ?

Comment: I have attached my whole HTML document and you can see I using the CDN that does have the `nav-pills` CSS in it.  I do have `<li>` in my code.  I am just not getting the "pill" effect as I should be

Comment: I am getting no effect at all

Comment: I've updated my comment. Please let me know if you still have problem ? In fact, if you use `//ajax/googleapis...` instead of `http://ajax/googleapis...`, and open index.html directly, you will get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` error message.